# Reshaping tensors to train with a Weibull distribution in R Keras

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I'm attempting to adapt the Weibull distribution first used here:
https://github.com/daynebatten/keras-wtte-rnn

A similar problem with translating this into R was tackled here, but it's not getting me to my solution: https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/354

My situation follows the following form. Namely, it's survival data, with either a failure time or the survival time to date, but with just one row per case, which doesn't fit either of the above cases (the original, for example, is the well-known jet engine failure data, and each engine has multiple rows containing data on multiple rounds of measurements over time.)

```r
library(keras)
library(tidyverse)

weibull_activate = function(ab) {
  a = k_exp(ab[, 1])
  b = k_softplus(ab[, 2])

  a = k_reshape(a, c(length(a), 1))
  b = k_reshape(b, c(length(b), 1))

  return(k_concatenate(list(a, b)))
}

weibull_loglik_continuous <- function(y_true, y_pred) {
  y_true = k_reshape(y_true, c(1, 2))
  y_pred = k_reshape(y_pred, c(1, 2))

  y_ = y_true[, 1]
  u_ = y_true[, 2]
  a_ = y_pred[, 1]
  b_ = y_pred[, 2]

  ya = (y_ + 1e-35) / a_
  return(-1 * k_mean(u_ * (k_log(b_) + b_ * k_log(ya)) - k_pow(ya, b_)))
}

set.seed(2019)

(data <- tibble(
  failure_time = runif(6),
  still_going  = sample(c(0, 1), 6, replace = TRUE),
  predictor    = jitter(failure_time)
))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   failure_time still_going predictor
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1       0.770            1    0.769 
#> 2       0.713            0    0.712 
#> 3       0.303            0    0.304 
#> 4       0.618            1    0.619 
#> 5       0.0505           0    0.0492
#> 6       0.0432           1    0.0438

model <-
  keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units       = 5,
              input_shape = 1) %>%
  layer_dense(2) %>%
  layer_activation(activation = weibull_activate) %>%
  compile(loss      = weibull_loglik_continuous,
          optimizer = "rmsprop")

fit(model,
    data %>% select(predictor) %>% as.matrix(),
    data %>% select(-predictor) %>% as.matrix(),
    batch_size = 3,
    epochs     = 1)
#> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords): InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 6 values, but the requested shape has 2
#>   [[Node: loss/activation_loss/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](_arg_activation_target_0_1/_25, loss/activation_loss/Reshape/shape)]]
#>   [[Node: loss/mul/_29 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_386_loss/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
#> 
#> Detailed traceback: 
#>   File "C:\Users\DHW\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1348, in fit
#>     validation_steps=validation_steps)
#>   File "C:\Users\DHW\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 253, in fit_loop
#>     outs = f(ins_batch)
#>   File "C:\Users\DHW\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 2897, in __call__
#>     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
#>   File "C:\Users\DHW\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1454, in __call__
#>     self._session._session, self._handle, args, status, None)
#>   File "C:\Users\DHW\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
#>     c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I'd think that this would mean that the loss function can just have 1 row hard-coded (at the second link, there are attempts to make it the same as the batch size and/or the number of rows per entity, e.g. engine). But no matter what I do, I get an error of some kind, either in the model compilation or the fitting. I've tried a few different things, including adjusting both the batch size and whether I include the `still_going` column in the training y matrix, but either way, the shape seems to be off. The one exception is that it *does* compile and train if the batch size is 1, and the training even seems to make sense (i.e. loss is a real number), but, of course, I don't want to do online learning, I want a stable model with large batch size. So, basically, there's some shape mismatch between the shape of the training y and the loss function, apparently in the length, that I can't resolve.

Comment: If the answer below doesn't solve the problem, please print the `K_int_shape` of each of the tensors and post them.

Comment: The `K_int_shape` of `y_true` is:
[[1]]
NULL
and the `K_int_shape` of `y_pred` is:
[[1]]
[1] 2
BTW, I got these by inserting `browser()` at the start of `weibull_loglik_continuous`.

Also, the base `print` output for the two tensors indicates that `y_pred` is shape `(2,)` while `y_true` is shape `shape=(?,)`.

Comment: What are the shapes of `ab`, `a` and `b` before reshape, `a` and `b` after reshape and the result of `weibull_activate`?

Comment: `ab` is `[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] 2`; `a` and `b` are both `NULL` before reshape and `1` after. What gets returned, though, after the `k_concatenate()`, has a shape of 2. I understand these as the two parameters for the Weibull distribution - one set of values for each observation. But, of course, the question is when and where these should be the whole batch of predicted parameters, and how to reshape the length accordingly.

Comment: (Actually, I might be confusing when the value pair is those parameters and when it's the time-death value pairs.)

Comment: I really don't have any idea of what those weird shapes mean. Can you print them the same way you got the `(2,)` and the `(?,)`, these sound like what a shape should look like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200971/discussion-between-dhw-and-daniel-moller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the details of this problem, but I see a basic problem here in `weibull_loglik_continuous`:

```
  y_true = k_reshape(y_true, c(1, 2))
  y_pred = k_reshape(y_pred, c(1, 2))
```

You are forcing the reshape of `y_true` and `y_pred` into something that has 1 for batch size.

For keeping the batch size, you need:

```
  y_true = k_reshape(y_true, c(-1, 2))
  y_pred = k_reshape(y_pred, c(-1, 2))
```

Now, I believe `y_true` and `y_pred` already come with the desired shape, if they come from `weibull_activate` and your data is actually 2D. (In which case you simply don't need the reshapes in `weibull_loglik_continuous`)

But you must fix `weibull_activate`:

```
a = k_reshape(a, c(-1, 1))
b = k_reshape(b, c(-1, 1))
```

The value `-1` is the correct way to reshape for a variable size dimension. The function `length`, probably an R function, will not work with tensorflow `Tensor`, because a tensor does not have data for having a length.

Comment: Replacing the 1s with those lengths gives me: `Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords): RuntimeError: Evaluation error: ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 2 elements to shape [2,2] (4 elements) for 'loss/activation_loss/Reshape_1' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [2], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [2,2].` This is specifically happening with the reshaping of `y_pred`, clearly. Maybe the problem is in the activation function. Note that this error is happening in the `compile()`, not the `fit()`.

Comment: The data are indeed just 2D, as in this example - each row is a separate observation with a single "survival" time, plus the boolean for "dead yet", and predictor values. So the batch sizes are just for training, and I guess those will change if, for example, I set a batch size of 3 and the training matrix is length 10. Re: the last axis, do you think `k_concatenate()` could help somewhere else here? Check its R help file, as it has an `axis` option.

Comment: Worked! I suspect that R Keras only recently implemented some of this functionality related to -1 and/or omitted indexes like `[,2]` without prior (re)shaping, and I just assumed that wouldn't work. Thank you!! Now I just need to worry about whether this code accurately embodies continuous Weibull distribution log-likelihood... ;)